# Ms Access Join tables in separate databases in delphi

Tags: database, delphi, ms-access, join, odbc

I use ADOConnection and AdoQuery to execute queries over MS Access (mdb) database. I want to join two tables in different databases (mdb files). I searched the web and find this solution:(example)

```
select [ZRDocs].* from [ZRDocs] left join [;database=d:\2222.mdb].[ZRDocItems] AS abc on [ZRDocs].[ID] = [abc].[DocID];
```

when I query this inside MSAccess, It works fine but when I execute this using ADOQuery, it throws an exception :

```
Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided.
```

I use Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider.

I also used complete connection string like this:

```
select [ZRDocs].* from [ZRDocs] 
left join [Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=d:
\2222.mdb;Mode=Share Deny None;Jet OLEDB:System database="";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=1;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;].[ZRDocItems] AS abc 
on [ZRDocs].[ID] = [abc].[DocID];
```

I searched google and many pages but found nothing.
So, how join two tables from different mdb (access) databases using delphi (ADO)?

Comment: What about include (link) external tables (include tables of database B inside database A)? Menu Insert -> Table -> Link Table (I suppose, I use different language). Anyway check this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-or-link-to-data-in-another-access-database-095ab408-89c7-45b3-aac2-58036e45fcf6

Comment: My app is portable but linking inside MS Access is not relative. So installing my app in other computers will make linking problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
select [ZRDocs].* 
from [ZRDocs] left join ([ZRDocItems] IN "D:\2222.mdb") AS abc 
     on [ZRDocs].[ID] = [abc].[DocID];
```

Comment: running inside MS Access :
     Syntax error in join operation. 
then it show "IN" in the query.

Comment: in access all joins need to be in brackets i think

Comment: No success even with brackets